# Create variable from the click of the button

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to know how I can get text that is in a EditText after I click a button, and this value is stored in a new variable, clear my EditText, and perform the same action again, so storing the values on different variables, and then perform a calculation, my big question is to store each value in a variable for different time, appreciate if someone can help! Thank you.

Comment: This is very vague. Why different variables? Use a list / array. Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EDITTEXT_ID);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        String myText = myEditText.getText().toString();
        //do whatever with myText;
        myEditText.setText("");
    }
});
```

Where BUTTON_ID and EDITTEXT_ID are the id's assigned to each respectively in your XML file

Comment: Excellent. And in just minutes.

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad and I can not express myself directly, I'll try to explain better

Every time I click a button I want to get the value of an EditText (so far so good), so that each time I perform the  I click need to store the value in a different variable, that's my problem

Comment: You could simply change the above to an array of Strings, which would be much easier to deal with

Comment: @Robert Instead of thinking about "storing the value in a different variable", it's easier to think of it as "adding the new value to a collection variable".  As suggested by others, a String array or a List of Strings could be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList listString = new ArrayList();

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EDITTEXT_ID);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
    listString.add(myEditText.getText().toString());
    myEditText.setText("");
}
});
```

Get String Values

```
for(int i=0;i<listString.size();i++)
{
           System.out.println("String values..."+listString.get(i).toString());
}
```